# Improve performance to get min & max datetime for given time range

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have following timeseries data table,

| Id | Object_Id | Datetime | Sensor1 | Sensor2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:01:00' | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:02:00' | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:03:00' | 5.5699381666667 | 81.342836833333 |
| 4 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:04:00' | 5.5668366666667 | 81.281143 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 48 | 175 | '2022-03-24 22:48:00' | NULL | NULL |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

in above table, I have **sensor1**, **sensor2** upto **sensor1000** columns and each has millions of time series records.

**Scenario1:**

I want to retrieve starttime(min datetime) and endtime(max datetime) records for multiple sensors `eg. sensor1 & sensor2`.

I have sensors array like below,

```
sensors = ["Sensor1", "Sensor2", ..., "sensorN"];
```

I loop through above array and construct below queries for Sensors eg for Sensor1,

```
(SELECT   datetime,id,sensor1
 FROM     timeseries
 where datetime between '2021-01-20 22:01:00' and '2024-01-20 00:17:00' limit 1)

Union ALL

(SELECT   datetime,id,sensor1
 FROM     timeseries
 where datetime between '2021-01-20 22:01:00' and '2024-01-20 00:17:00' ORDER BY datetime DESC limit 1)
```

for Sensor2,

```
(SELECT   datetime,id,sensor2
 FROM     timeseries
 where datetime between '2021-01-20 22:01:00' and '2024-01-20 00:17:00' limit 1)

Union ALL

(SELECT   datetime,id,sensor2
 FROM     timeseries
 where datetime between '2021-01-20 22:01:00' and '2024-01-20 00:17:00' ORDER BY datetime DESC limit 1)
```

This query works as expected. Observe that I created individual query for **sensor1** and **sensor2** as I want to handle failure scenario for individual sensor.

The problem is in real life scenario, I have millions of records, around **50 to 70 GB data**.

When I run above query (for just **sensor1** & **sensor2**), it takes significant amount of time to return the result. What if user is trying with **multiple sensors** (for functional requirement I can select up to 35 sensors in one go). Trust me it takes time and we can observe it in real implementation.

In [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/f43xBmew) it works smoothly as It has only 150 records.

How can I improve/optimize the performance of this query?

FYI, for each requested sensor, query is prepared in **Node/express** app and then app connects to MySQL server where I execute **each query** using for loop:

```
const queryResults = await Promise.all(
      queries.map(async (query) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
          db.query(query, [], (err, result) => {
            if (err) {

              return resolve([]);                // If individual query fails then return empty array
            } else {
    
              return resolve(result);
            }
          })
        );
      })
    );
```

Comment: I would use min and max functions so I wonder why you don't, Also limit without an order by is not good practice.

Comment: Your table in the dbfiddle has no index on the `datetime` column. Is that also true in your production database?

Comment: What Engine are you using?  Does the table really have 1003 columns?  What MySQL version?  Are the values `DOUBLEs`?

Comment: Are you looking for the first row after some datetime and the last row before some other datetime?  That sounds like "groupwise max"

Comment: See my blogs on [groupwise max](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) and [sensors](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_sensor)